# Как сделать подгрузку изображений с прогресс-баром?

Tags: javascript, upload, progress-bar

Как сделать подгрузку больших изображений (пути к ним занесены в массив) в фоне с отображением прогресс-бара по размеру изображений (индикация: сколько уже скачено к общему размеру файла)?

Все, что находил, связано с input-file и аякс, в котором и берется общий размер файла и сколько уже скачено.

Answer (score 1):

Все верно. Image предоставляет возможность получить информацию только об успешности загрузки, но не о ее процессе. Поэтому вариант с XMLHttpRequest видится самым простым способом решения вашей задачи.